# Script for checking usage of password by user on his Windows machine

Tags: shell, powershell

I wondering is there opportunity to check by running shell script to check usage of  password for my user account on my machine.

Comment: You mean successful/unsuccessful log in attempts?

Comment: Although you're asking for a code solution, your question is actually about the OS itself (How can I audit logon/logoff). I think this would be better placed on [su] instead of here.

Comment: I want to know that user has password when he tries to login in machine. It`s security question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off topic, it would better fit on Super User. (As already stated out by @JamesC.)

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. [SO] isn't a forum nor a free script writing service. Own research and code attempts are expected.  Hint `Get-LocalUser $Env:USERNAME | Format-List *`